# WMI vs NETSH for Adding IP's to NIC with C#?

Tags: c#, wmi, windows-server-2008-r2, netsh, nic

I am writing a small tool to simplify some of the stuff I do at work day to day, and the Windows GUI for adding IP's to the NIC is horrid. I am looking to find a decent way to...

- Pull all Static IP's that are currently on the NIC (just to see a list)
- Add either a single or range of IP's to the NIC

I found [Configuring TCP/IP Settings using WMI and C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/cstcpipwmi.aspx) and [THIS](http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/38440-netsh-interface/page__view__findpost__p__940222) snippet for adding an IP to the NIC using netsh. What would be the best way to approach this and would solution should I use to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and after some research i choose WMI.

I think netsh is better if you use the script alone (i means not in a code).
Personnaly i want to configure NIC in a c# code so WMI look more practical and i's quite easy to use it with a config file made in xml.

Comment: Did you get it working with WMI? I eventually just used netsh in my application as I needed to go ahead and get something up and working.

Comment: I did'nt get it working yet because i have so many other things to do. If you handle netsh it's good to get something working fast but if you have time i would be great to do a POC (proof of concept) with the two tools (WMI & Netsh).